# jQuery scrollTop with "else if" statement doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, var, scrolltop

I'm trying to addClass and removeClass to a div based on top scrolling with jquery.

I created these two variables:

```
var mainHeight = $('#main-image').height()/1.10;
var footHeight = $('body').height() - $('footer').height();
```

And this is the script that doesn't works:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > mainHeight) {
        $('#box_centrale').removeClass('chat-bottom, chat-top');

    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > footHeight) {
        $('#box_centrale').removeClass('chat-bottom');
        $('#box_centrale').addClass('chat-top');    

    } else {
        $('#box_centrale').removeClass('chat-top');
        $('#box_centrale').addClass('chat-bottom');         
    }
});
```

The "if" and "else" statement works but "else if" statement doesn't work...
Have you any idea why does not work?
(I apologize for my English)

Comment: Define "doesn't work". At what point do you set the `mainHeight` and `footHeight` values? When you debugged it, were they what you expected?

Comment: Are the `if` statements ordered reasonably? E.g., should you be checking against `footHeight` first? Because it sounds like `mainHeight` would always be larger than `footHeight` unless you have an unusually-sized foot.

Comment: The method .removeClass() expects a space seperated list of classes to remove, not comma seperated. Maybe that's it already ...

Comment: well does it go into the first if?

Comment: "If" and "else" statement work properly, now I try to change the order of actions to see if anything changes. Unfortunately I am not an expert programmer to jquery.

Comment: The "footHeight" variable  represents a scroll greater than the other variable; that is the height of the body minus the height of the footer.

Instead mainHeight represents the "hero-section" height divided by 1.1

Answer (score 0):

I solved! There was an error in the second variable, missing parentheses to the operation. I decide to create a jsfiddle with an example of what I wanted to do, hoping that it will help someone in the future.

Thank you all

Here the link:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9nts6c9/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var mainHeight = $('#header').height()/2;
var footHeight = ($('body').height() - $('#footer').height() - 290);

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < mainHeight) {
        $('#fixed-box').css({
            "bottom" : "calc(100% - 310px)",
        });

    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > footHeight) {
        $('#fixed-box').css({
            "bottom" : "calc(260px)",
        });

    } else {
        $('#fixed-box').css({
            "bottom" : "calc(50% - 25px)",
        });         
    }
});
```

});